# Antonymic idiom for "adding fuel to the fire"

Tags: terminology

Please tell me an antonymic idiom for "adding fuel to the fire". With meaning something like "downplay the problem", "close eyes on problem".

Comment: I think your question is confusing because "adding fuel to the fire" refers to doing something which makes a situation worse, whereas "downplay the problem" refers to changing perception of a situation without actually affecting the situation itself.  But an antonym to "adding fuel to the fire" could be _"defuse the situation"_.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have used the direct opposite "*douse the flames*" but apparently that is not common enough an idiom.

Otherwise the one that's used more widely would probably be "*stop the rot*".

Answer (score 0):

My first thought had to do with fuel (oil) as well, meaning the actual opposite of adding fuel to the fire:

> Pour oil on troubled waters

Which means to calm a problematic situation. (ref. http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/288150.html )

However, your question seems to indicate you are not looking for an opposite meaning of "making a problem bigger", but more for "make a problem more important than it is".

Someone who understates a problem, or ignores its importance can be said to be **complacent** about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **[turn a blind eye](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/turn+a+blind+eye)**

> to ignore something and pretend you do not see it.
>
> *The usher turned a blind eye to the little boy who sneaked into the theater.*
>
> *How can you turn a blind eye to all those starving children?*

Also consider **[bury your head in the sand](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bury+head+in+the+sand)**

> to ignore or hide from obvious signs of danger. (Alludes to an ostrich, which is believed incorrectly to hide its head in a hole in the ground when it sees danger.)
>
> *Stop burying your head in the sand.*
>
> *Look at the statistics on smoking and cancer.*

Answer (score 0):

The opposite of "adding fuel to the fire" could be, in some cases:

> **to take the heat out of** the debate (or out of the situation, conflict,
>   issue).

Answer (score 0):

[Pours water on](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=STW&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&q=%22pours%20water%20on%22&oq=%22pours%20water%20on%22&gs_l=serp.12..0i30l3j0i5i30l7.99338.99503.0.102337.2.2.0.0.0.0.146.165.1j1.2.0....0...1c.1.32.serp..1.1.19.fWZ9hm7cBaQ):

> Nate Silver Pours Water On Media's Shutdown Narrative
>
> Success of Israeli swimmers pours water on Arab boycott in Dubai
>
> Fire chief pours water on union's safety complaint - Winnipeg
>
> Shock Badgers' defeat pours water on league success hopes
>
> Illinois utility targeted by cybersaboteurs? US pours water on the idea

In addition to having water poured on them, ideas, plans and such may also be [scotched](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scotched):

> to put an end to: scotched rumors of a military takeover